# Is it possible to create a DApp that uses Bitcoin, Lumen, etc over the Ethereum BlockChain?

Tags: wallets, tokens, bitcoin

I'm a total newcomer to Ethereum, so please forgive me if my Question has been answered before.

I'm trying to build a DApp that allows users to "import" their current Bitcoin for example, and spend it using my DApp. Is this generally possible?

If you could also point me in the right direction of where to start, links, articles, etc. I'd deeply appreciate it!

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, you would need a service of some kind that listens to the given blockchain transaction records to detect transfers and confirmations from different users.

If you want them to be able to execute smart contract functions, they will have to run Metamask or another web3 provider, and have a valid ethereum balance on the calling account to pay for the gas costs of function calls.

If you don't want to force users to use web3 or have an ethereum balance, then you will need to pay for the gas costs yourself. For example, in your Dapp you could have a button for a user to roll a set of dice. When the button is clicked, an account *you* control with a valid ethereum balance calls the smart contract function for the user.

Comment: Fantastic Answer!